# Face motion detection technique in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, face-detection

I am searching for face detection technique in iPhone. In my app I want to detect moving motion of face using camera. So, if you have any idea about that then please guide me. I am trying with accelerometer but I could not get any idea. So, if you have any idea about that then please guide me.

Comment: I guess your best bet is starting [here](http://computer-vision-talks.com/2011/02/building-opencv-for-iphone-in-one-click/)

Answer (score 3):

Try open CV library for reference here's a [link](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2009/08/09/near-realtime-face-detection-on-the-iphone-w-opencv-port-wcodevideo/) try it out

Comment: Hi Radix thanks for reply..I am using your link but I have some doubt about OpenCV Lib..haw can I install it?There is link for that but it could not open.I make all code as describe in link.

Comment: The code is given in this link and it opened at my end 

http://code.google.com/p/morethantechnical/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FFaceDetector-iPhone%2FClasses

Comment: @ Radix Thanks,I am trying that code..Is there any need to add openCV lib in it?

Comment: Hi, I am working on your link in it after insatll OpenCV framwork I hound some errors,If you dn't mind then please would you help me for that.I used "http://www.computer-vision-software.com/blog/2009/04/opencv-vs-apple-iphone/" link for install OpenCV and found 1) "/Users/admin/Desktop/FaceDetector1/Classes/mycvHaarDetectObjects.cpp:3:0 /Users/admin/Desktop/FaceDetector1/Classes/mycvHaarDetectObjects.cpp:3:16: error: cv.h: No such file or directory"  2)  error: 'cvAlignPtr' was not declared in this scope

Comment: The SVN repo is missing the .xcodeproj file. I wonder why and how to workaround that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you should use OpenCV for this project, but getting it to work in XCode is tricky.

**EDIT**: The original link I posted is down (presumably because the author has written a book), but the OpenCV project now seems to have an iOS package here:

http://opencv.org/downloads.html

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Looks like it went down on May 3rd (although at the time of this writing, it's still in Google's cache).  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late, but you could use this for continues face detection:
https://github.com/evermeer/EVFaceTracker

Answer (score -1):

There is a ready-made library dubbed Phonect that does this.
It's a motion detection engine for the iPhone -

Checkout the website at:
www.phonect.me

and the showcase app at:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/phonect/id466260946?mt=8

Cheers!
Oded.